# Restrict users from viewing page in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm having a problem with the website that I'm making. I'm making a website where users will be able to go and watch a short video, after that they can Sign Up and get a link to verify their emails. The email goes to their inputted email and they have a verification link which leads to another page. That page has a button which leads to a Full Video. Now I want to prevent users from viewing verify page and the page where users see full video before they verify their emails. I'm fairly new to PHP and I tried something, I think it's not that good but I'm still learning.

I wanted to redirect users when they go to `localhost/verify.php` and allow them to go on the page when the URL is `localhost/verify.php?verified=1`, that ?verified=1 URL is being sent to their emails.

But whatever I type it redirects index.php

**verify.php**

```
 if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'verify.php')){
    header('Location: index.php');
  }
  else if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'verify.php?verified=1')){
    header('Location: verify.php');
  }
```

Is there any way I can do this better since the users don't have register option and I'm not saving any sessions.

Comment: you can make it from your database by adding a new column in your users table called `verified` it will take `true` or `false` and in every single page check if he verified or not

Comment: I said im not using register option or any, its not even connected to datebase

Comment: All a person has to do then is copy the URL into a text editor and manually add ?verify=1 to it.  Or paste that version of the link to a forum or chat for other people to use.  If you aren't going to use a database with logins, one-time-use tokens, or account ID tokens with usage limits you can't really secure the page.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you are not creating users, you can have a table that just represents these email addresses that contains a `key, email, verified(bool), verification_token(unique string)` then in the controller for the verified route you can check if that verification token exists, mark the user as verified and pass them along to the video. This also allows you to store a that token in a cookie that you could check for anytime they hit that normal endpoint without the query parameter you could still treat them as verified. It's not full on auth, but it sounds like you don't want a full blown authenticatable user for these emails

Comment: ^ this is what I would do. Good solution.